# Read one file and write to another C

Tags: c, recursion, file-io

I am trying to read from files and write to a temp file. However, I am stuck in an infinite loop right now. The function below is called multiple times by a recursive function that goes through directories to read files.

My approach is that I would read each word from one file, then those words to another file.

The function I have works fine if I just print out each word. It prints out each word in each file in all directories. However, when I try to start writing to a temp file (the code commented out), I am stuck in the while loop.

On the other hand, if I just call the function once in a test program where I just read from one file in the current directory, and write to a temp file, it's fine.

This is what I have (`fileName` when passed in is actually the absolute path, and I do `../tmp` so it does not get caught in the recursion function):

```
void fileReadWrite(char *pattern, char *before, char *replace, char *fileName) {
   FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "r");

   if (file != NULL) {
      int ch, word = 0;
      while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
         if (isspace(ch) || ispunct(ch)) {
            if (word) {
               word = 0;
               putchar('\n');
            }
         }
         else {
            word = 1;
            putchar(ch);

            /*
            FILE *f = fopen("../tmp", "wb"); // create and write
            if (f == NULL)
            {    
               printf("Error opening file!\n");       
               exit(1);
            }

            fprintf(f, "Some text"); // Or fprintf(f, ch);

            fclose(f);
            */
         }
      }
      fclose(file);
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's stuck in the loop? Have you tried stepping through the code, line by line, in a debugger to make sure that the code you show is the problem? Maybe it's the code walking through the directory that's causing the problem, when you suddenly create a new file? You should really learn how to use a debugger to help you with problems like these.

Comment: Also, why are you opening the temporary file in *binary* mode? (It shouldn't cause a problem, but if you're writing text to it then open it in text mode.)

Comment: Isnt' it the case that if you step into a directory and then write to ../tmp you might actually end up reading that ../tmp file again once you climb up in the recursion again?

Comment: I put a print statement before and after the while loop and it never hits the second one. My recursive function only looks at sub directories so it's fine there, I think.

Comment: The function you posted is not tied to recursion. It accepts a filename which you read and write to another file. If this is getting stuck, it is getting stuck for another reason, not related to recursion. Is this the complete code for this function? Or is it a minimal representation?

Comment: It is the complete code for the function. It is called by a function that does recursion.

Comment: If the file you are reading isn't a regular file, you may never get an EOF. You should just check if `ch` has value or not.

Comment: There are two possible problems I can see causing this: The first is that the loop will be slower because you open, write to, close and reopen etc. the temporary file in the loop, but unless you have a very big input file this should not cause a problem. The other possible problem might be because there is some kind of lock on the file or parent directory, causing `fopen` to block until that lock is released. The code itself looks okay, and shouldn't cause a problem like you're describing. You ***really*** need to step through the code in a debugger to see what's actually happening.

Comment: You could also be running out of file descriptor if you recurse while files are open. Although this will usually throw an error.

Comment: Every time you open "../tmp" to write to it, you discard the old contents (lose what you wrote last time) because you're opening in write mode...

Comment: I ran it with a sample file and it worked just fine. Outputted one word per line to stderr and filled `../tmp` with one line of "Some text" (`"w"` truncates the file upon opening it).

Comment: The code has multiple issues, though. Might be a good idea to migrate it to codereview.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Based on the code you posted, I am guessing the calling function changes directory as it recurse thereby creating multiple `../tmp` in the directory tree. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: @alvits No, the function doesn't change the CWD so there's no recursion, just lots of reopening and rewriting of the same file.

Comment: @PSkocik Yeah same here when I try running it with just one file. But when I try running it in my actual program where there is this function recursively goes through files in subdirectories, it does print out the words in files through putchar(ch). But when I uncomment that section up there, it just does not go any where and I have to Ctrl C.

Comment: !!!! It worked but I don't understand !!!! Can someone explain this? So I move FILE *f = fopen("../tmp", "wb"); and fclose(f); outside the while loop, and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing in your code that suggests an infinite loop.  However, if `fileName` is very large, you could be opening and closing "..\tmp" millions of times.  As Joachim Pileborg points out in the comments, you should open that file just once at the beginning of your function, and close it again at the end.

If you want to convince yourself that you are *not* in an infinite loop, print out the value of `ch` on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I did this and it worked. But I don't understand why though. Can someone explain it please?

```
void fileReadWrite(char *pattern, char *before, char *replace, char *fileName) {
   FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "r");
   FILE *f = fopen("../tmp", "wb"); // MOVE HERE

   if (file != NULL) {
      int ch, word = 0;
      while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
         if (isspace(ch) || ispunct(ch)) {
            if (word) {
               word = 0;
               putchar('\n');
            }
         }
         else {
            word = 1;
            putchar(ch);

            /*

            if (f == NULL)
            {    
               printf("Error opening file!\n");       
               exit(1);
            }

            fprintf(f, "Some text"); // Or fprintf(f, ch);


            */
         }
      }
      fclose(file);
      fclose(f); // MOVE HERE
   }
}
```

Comment: Just guessing, but maybe it wasn't hung up (previously) but *appeared* to be because it ran *very* slowly, spending a lot of time opening and closing the (output) file over and over (once for almost every character of every file).  Further, it may have looked like it stuck after the first char was output because the file was being emptied and overwritten every time ("a" would've added to the end of the file... but "w" starts with an empty file each time you open)... so the output file would never have more than 1 char (or "Some text").